# Display two number pickers on textview

Tags: java, android, android-number-picker

I made a created two number pickers to fake as timepicker for the simple purpose of been able to rotate 0 - 30 repeatedly, which works.

But now I want to display these two number pickers to a textview.

So if the numberpickers shows what's in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD93v.png)

then the timeoutput should display this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFcCt.png)

Here's my code:

```
    public void timepicker() {

        mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
        mMinuteSpinner.setMaxValue(3);
        mMinuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(new String[]{"00", "30", "00", "30"});
        mMinuteSpinner.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
        mHourSpinner.setMinValue(0);
        mHourSpinner.setMaxValue(23);
        String[] hours = new String[24];
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            hours[i] = String.format("%02d", i );
        }
        mHourSpinner.setDisplayedValues(hours);
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

        boolean advanced = (newVal == 0 && oldVal == 3) || (newVal == 2 && oldVal == 1);
        boolean regressed = (newVal == 3 && oldVal == 0) || (newVal == 1 && oldVal == 2);

        if (advanced) {
            mHourSpinner.setValue(mHourSpinner.getValue() + 1);
        } else if (regressed) {
            mHourSpinner.setValue(mHourSpinner.getValue() - 1);
        }
```

I also tried variations of below:

```
        timeoutput.setText("" + mHourSpinner.getValue() + "h" + mMinuteSpinner.getValue());
```

But it didn't work. Getvalue seems to get the position of the number instead of the actual number.

The change to display textview also seems to only happen when the user rotates the numbers on the right(minutes), when the change should also occur if they rotate the numbers on the left(hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause**

- When you select the `mHourSpinner`, nothing happens because you forgot to call `setOnValueChangedListener` on it.
- [getValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker#getValue()) just return the value of the `Picker` not displayed value, you must use [getDisplayedValues()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker#getDisplayedValues()) to do that.

**Solution:** Change your code to

```
public void timepicker() {
    mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
    mMinuteSpinner.setMaxValue(3);
    mMinuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(new String[]{"00", "30", "00", "30"});
    mMinuteSpinner.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

    mHourSpinner.setMinValue(0);
    mHourSpinner.setMaxValue(23);
    String[] hours = new String[24];
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        hours[i] = String.format("%02d", i);
    }
    mHourSpinner.setDisplayedValues(hours);
    mHourSpinner.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

    displaySelectedHourAndMinute();
}

@Override
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    displaySelectedHourAndMinute();
}

private void displaySelectedHourAndMinute() {
    String hour = mHourSpinner.getDisplayedValues()[mHourSpinner.getValue()];
    String minute = mMinuteSpinner.getDisplayedValues()[mMinuteSpinner.getValue()];
    timeoutput.setText(hour + "h" + minute);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. This one took me time. Smart man.

Comment: @MrAndroid If this answer solved your problem, please make it as the answer, It will help me improving my answers in the furure.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did not set `onValueChangeListener` to `mHourSpinner`.
Try this instead:

```
public void timepicker() {

    mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
    mMinuteSpinner.setMaxValue(3);
    mMinuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(new String[]{"00", "30", "00", "30"});
    mMinuteSpinner.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
    mHourSpinner.setMinValue(0);
    mHourSpinner.setMaxValue(23);
    mHourSpinner.setOnValueChangedListener(this); // Add this line
    String[] hours = new String[24];
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        hours[i] = String.format("%02d", i );
    }
    mHourSpinner.setDisplayedValues(hours);
}
```

And for your `onValueChangeListener`, instead of reading the oldVal and newVal of from any of the spinners, you get the value directly from the spinners like this:

```
@Override
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
   //Remove the unnecessary lines and just update the value
   timeoutput.setText(mHourSpinner.getDisplayedValue()[mHourSpinner.getValue()] + "h" + mMinuteSpinner.getDisplayedValue()[mMinuteSpinner.getValue()]);
}
```

Comment: Okay, so the right spinner outputs now, but the code you put for setText is one I've tried before. The minutes spinner brings back the array position. So instead of displaying 30, I'll get back 1, which is the position, not the actual string.

I also changed

hours[i] = Integer.toString(i)
to
hours[i] = String.format("%02d", i ), to have 0 in front of single digits.

so right now I get an output as

4h0

instead of 

04h00

Comment: Ahh, I see your problems, I have changed it to `getDisplayedValue()` instead of `getValue()`